# jquery mobile enable long text truncate

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Jquery mobile intelligently truncates h1 h2 tags in header and footer. I've seen many tutorials how to avoid this. But my need is different, I've custom div without data-role. And I need to truncate h2 h3 heading text inside this div.

How do I enable truncate long text on custom text headings?

Comment: Like this? http://fiddle.jshell.net/P9SS4/3/ give the div `.ui-header` and `h2,3` a `.ui-title`.

Comment: You can also simply create a class out of the following style elements: 
<div><h1 style="text-overflow: ellipsis;overflow: hidden;white-space: nowrap;">This is very long text This is very long text This is very long text This is very long text This is very long text </h1></div>

Comment: @Sheetal please make this an answer.

Comment: @Omar Thanks! but, I preferred the other answer :)

Comment: Both are the same. Copy style of the classes I mentioned in my previous comment. That's all. Good luck.

Comment: @Omar not really, your comment could suggest that behind the scenes jquery-mobile was using classes + js to shorten text. The other comment made it clear it was css part.

Comment: `.ui-header .ui-title { min-height: 1.1em; text-align: center; font-size: 16px; display: block; margin: .6em 30% .8em; padding: 0; text-overflow: ellipsis; overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; outline: 0 !important; }` :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also simply create a class out of the following style elements:

```
<div>
   <h1 style="text-overflow: ellipsis;overflow: hidden;white-space: nowrap;">
    This is very long text This is very long text This is very long text This is very long text This is very long text
   </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Very nice.  I'd like to see something similar for the toolbar button labels.  Any ideas?